# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #47: Error inflating class unknown

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, android-logcat

I am new in Android and trying to make simple App .I am trying to run my app on Android device but it is crashing evrytime. please help.

Here is my Manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Inspection"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_inspection"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

Main Acivity class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
public void onClickemergency(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Inspection.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

Main Activity Xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ff2629"
    android:text="@string/breaks"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/news"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:paddingEnd="20dp"
    android:onClick="onClickemergency"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/check"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/checks"
    android:background="#1B9AF7"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:src="@drawable/bev"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#1B9AF7"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:text="@string/pap"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  enter code here  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Logcat File

```
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidbegin.carpiko/com.androidbegin.carpiko.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #47: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2192)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2241)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1204)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5049)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: please provide your complete error log.

Comment: main_activity.xml is not complete, missing RelativeLayout closing tag.